# Google Sheets: Find an email in a range of emails where some cells have 2-3 emails in it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a range `A2:A` with emails (multiple cells in that range have 2 or 3 emails in one cell).

Also, I have a cell `C3` that has an email in it. This `C3` cell might have 1 or 2 emails in it (as shown in the screenshot below, please take a look at `E3` cell).

And I want to check if the email (or any of the emails) from the `C3` cell is in that range of emails `A2:A`.

The problem is that multiple cells have 2 or 3 emails in them and I don't know how loop through each email in one cell.

Here's the screenshot
[image: screenshot]

I was thinking about creating a Google Apps Script that checks if a cell has 2 emails it takes each email in that cell and loops through the entire range of emails. But there's probably a more simpler way of doing this.

Hope you understand what I'm saying :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you want to do if you find them in the list?

Comment: @Cooper I just want to check whether a client with an email in 'C3' cell is a new client or an old client (if his email is in the range A2:A he's an old client), and return either TRUE or FALSE. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function findEmails() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var vA=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var list=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]}).filter(function(e){return e;});
  var found=[];//stores the email found and the cell it came from in A1 notation
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][2]) {
      var emA=vA[i][2].toString().split('\n');emA.forEach(function(e,j){var idx=list.indexOf(e);if(idx>-1){found.push({email:e,location:sh.getRange(i+1,3).getA1Notation()});}});
    }
    if(vA[i][4]) {
      var emA=vA[i][4].toString().split('\n');emA.forEach(function(e,j){var idx=list.indexOf(e);if(idx>-1){found.push({email:e,location:sh.getRange(i+1,5).getA1Notation()});}});
    }
  }
  Logger.log(found);
}
```

This is what found looked like in my example:

```
[{location=C1, email=email4@gmail.com}, 
{location=E1, email=email7@gmail.com}, 
{location=E1, email=email13@gmail.com}]
```

These emails won't be the same as yours as I used my own data.  But you can get the idea of how to do it by reviewing the code.  I do expect that the emails will always be separated by '\n' (line feeds);